# Cordova запись информации в json

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

Есть простое приложение (простой список дел на день). Есть потребность хранить информацию о сделаных делах локально, т.е. не используя интернет. С `JS` перенести данные в файл невозможно, может существуют какие-то плагины `cordova`? Или другой способ.
Спасибо, жду ответа.

Comment: Есть SQLite, работает локально

Answer (score 2):

Конечно же существует. Локальное хранилище, не требует никаких плагинов.
Сохранение данных

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'param');
```

Загрузка данных

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```

Проверка на наличие сохранённых данных

```
if(localStorage.getItem('key')){//Данные записаны в хранилище}
if(!localStorage.getItem('key')){//Данные в хранилище не записаны}
```

Если нужно данные хранить именно в файле, то придется подключать [плагин](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file).

Comment: ТС'у надо сохранить в файл вроде как...

Comment: Добавил ссылку на плагин